# How to add effect on CanvasGeometry

Tags: uwp, graphics2d, win2d, windows-composition-api

It seems to me that all the effects available in Win2D are for drawing image.

What about `CanvasGeometry`? How do I draw a `CanvasGeometry` using, say glowing effect ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Geometry`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Geometry_CanvasGeometry.htm) objects provide a means of drawing and manipulating geometric shapes. It has `CreatePolygon`,`CreatePath`method could be used to create geometric shapes.

For glowing effect, you could refer this [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/blob/master/ExampleGallery/GlowTextCustomControl.cs#L17).

```
private void DoEffect(CanvasDrawingSession ds, Size size, float amount)
{
    size.Width = size.Width - ExpandAmount;
    size.Height = size.Height - ExpandAmount;

    var offset = (float)(ExpandAmount / 2);           

    using (var textLayout = CreateTextLayout(ds, size))
    using (var textCommandList = new CanvasCommandList(ds))
    {
        using (var textDs = textCommandList.CreateDrawingSession())
        {                     
            textDs.DrawTextLayout(textLayout, 0, 0, GlowColor);
        }

         glowEffectGraph.Setup(textCommandList, amount);
         ds.DrawImage(glowEffectGraph.Output, offset, offset);

         ds.DrawTextLayout(textLayout, offset, offset, TextColor);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, `CanvasCommandList` did the trick. I was looking for something like it.